# "Can't find any matching row in the user table" when attempting "SET PASSWORD"

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, users

When I do `SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user` I see that I have a user named `myuser` on `%`. I tried setting that users password thusly:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'myuser'@'%' = 'mypassword';
```

Doing so, however, resulted in this error:

```
Error Code: 1133. Can't find any matching row in the user table
```

Superficially this sounds like [Error Code: 1133. Can't find any matching row in the user table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/69921/83612) but it's not the same because the username and password *do* appear to exist...

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using 'native' passwords, or some other plugin?

Comment: Use [ALTER USER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-user.html#alter-user-authentication), not SET PASSWORD. Test user name/host values using HEX() function.